# Debian does not boot with Xen

Tags: debian, boot, xen

I set up some new Hardware to run a debian xen host on.

Installing Debian worked fine, but when i installed `xen-system-amd64` and tried to boot with xen hypervisor the screen stays black after the grub menu and the system seems to not be booting properly.

Hardware:
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 7600
RAM: 2x 16GB DDR5-4800MT/S ECC
SSD: 2x 1TB NVMe SSD 
Mainboard: Asus prime b650M-A II

I did set up a serial console trying to spot the problem here is what i caught https://pastebin.com/cSQ051cF .

I tried to roule out as much config complexity as possible, therefor i reinstalled debian without lvm / raid and used the default formating config. Unfortunately the result stayed the same.

I further tryied debian testing which gets me a bit further (yay display output) but seems still to fail
[image: screenshot of the output]

I'm running out of ideas and don't get what the kernel log is trying to tell me, therefor i'm here for some help/hints.

Comment: After some hints from friends I switched off SMT, after that the system boots.
Seems like xen isn't yet ready for such a modern cpu

Comment: Which version of xen-hypervisor does debian install?